# How to embed .wav audio files into PDF?

Tags: pdf, media9, multimedia, attachfile, audio

I have tried using packages media9, media15, multimedia, and attachfile, but I can not for the life of me figure it out.  I don't know if I need to install anything for these packages or if using the '\usepackage{...}' is all I need.  In answering this question please assume I have now knowledge of latex.

Firstly, I am using overleaf to code and so I am wondering if I am able to play the audio file to check that it works right in overleaf? or do I need to download the PDF?

Secondly, I've tried using other peoples codes for both .mp3 and .wav files but I can not get any of them working.  I have uploaded the .mp3 and .wav audio files into overleaf as well as a .jpg image that I intend on using, and I see the image on the pdf page but I am never able to hear or play the audio.

Code examples I used;

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[implicit=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{multimedia}

\begin{document}
\sound[inlinesound]{\includegraphics{example-image}}{1024Tone.wav}
\end{document}
```

and

```
\textattachfile{myvideo.mp4}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{myi‌​con}}
```

and

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{default}
\usecolortheme{crane}
\usefonttheme{serif}

% the relevant packages for including sound files
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{attachfile}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Here's a button that plays a sound}

% link to an audio file called "fish.wav" stored in same directory
% when the button is clicked the sound file should play

\begin{center}
\movie[label=fish]{}{fish.wav} % defines the file the movie points to
\hyperlinkmovie{fish}{\beamerbutton{``fish''}} % generate the button with the link around it
\end{center}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**Overall, I would like to be able to import *.wav audio files* into latex such that the PDF once downloaded, will have all the audio files in them and anyone with the PDF file can click a play button on each file and hear the audio.**

Comment: Does it work if you download the pdf and open it with adobe reader?

Comment: Ohhh okay yea it is working in adobe reader.  I was originally just opening the pdf using chrome.  Is there a way to have the audio files work in chrome as well, or does it have to being using adobe reader?

Comment: Multimedia support in pdf viewers is nothing one can take for granted. There are not a lot of viewers which support it. Chances are usually best with adobe reader. In particular I don't think the overleaf viewer has multimedia support enabled.